# parsing xml content on windows phone 7 using tcp sockets

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, windows-phone-7, xmpp

I am working on an application for windows phone 7.

I have a to parse xml stream using tcp sockets in c# silverlight. I am trying it using xmlreader and memory stream but it is of no help. When memory stream is updated by a receive async call, xmlreader has no impact of that reader.

Please help me on how to parse streaming xml from sockets.

I have a xmlReader such that:

```
memoryStream= new MemoryStream();   
_xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream, xmlReaderSettings, context);
```

now memoryStream is updated as:

```
byte []buffer = "initialized with some xml bytes such as <node1> data </node1>"
```

as this buffer is filled by socket receiveasync operation which is xml.
now i need to update the my data. so I do this...

memoryStream = memoryStream.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);

Now when i do this _reader.read fails. I don't why is this happening. otherwise is there is xmlpullparser (sax) like thing as we have in android os for xml parsing

```
while (_reader.Read())
            {
                switch (_reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        {
                            node = new XElement(_reader.Name);
                            xmlBuildStack.Push(node);

                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                  .....
```

is there any other way possible to parse xml which comes from tcp socket stream as i am working on chat application which uses xmpp xml stanzas. please help me in solving this scenario.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, could you try to clarify your question? Do you already have some code to share that will show what you are trying to do? This will make it easier for is to give advice.

Comment: Try: First fill the MemoryStream, then create the XmlReader. Also set stream.Position = 0; when switching r/w

Comment: my stream is a xml which  comes in fragmented form i.e in packets from sockets. so I need to fill my stream with the content i receive.if I fill memory stream first and then create xmlreader.it won't full fill the purpose.As on first receiveAsync i get half xml content and in next receiveAsyncs i get my xml content which is needed to be appended to the stream to make it proper xml stanza. if this is not the right method then how can i do it.

Comment: Can't you create a new MemoryStream and XmlReader every time you receive a new buffer?

Comment: @KooKiz actually the thing is that xml content comes through tcp sockets.And the content which arrives through the socket might not be a proper xml content i.e xml could arrive in 2-3 receive async calls.

Comment: @rakesh kumar seems tricky. You should check the protocol documentation, there's usually a way to tell every chunk of data apart. In your case, maybe all xml content starts and ends with the same elements? Then you can concat the buffers in a string buffer of your own, and forward it to the xmlReader once you have the start and end element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemoryStream` doesn't work the way you want it to. When the `XmlReader` reads to the current end (i.e. consumes all of the current data), it's going to report that it's reached end of file.

What you really need is to wrap a stream around the TCP socket. Probably the easiest thing to do would be to use a [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) rather than a raw socket. The `GetStream` method will do what you want--provide a stream from which you can create an `XmlReader`.

Another option is to create a type of stream that does what you're asking. That is, it lets one thread put data in and another take data out. But the consumer doesn't report end of file until the producer *says* end of file has occurred.

I wrote and published something like this a few months back. See [Building a New Type of Stream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852).

Honestly, though ... `TcpClient` would be my preference in this case.

Comment: Jim Mischel  : TcpClient api is not available for windows phone 7 mango version.

Comment: @rakesh kumar: What about `NetworkStream`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx

Comment: @rakesh kumar: Then the only solution I see is to either buffer everything from the socket before creating the `MemoryStream`, or going with something like the `ProducerConsumerStream` that I showed in that article.

Comment: even then XmlReader will read till the end and then xmlreader.read will return false.

Comment: I tried your(ProducerConsumerStream) class but when I pass it to Xmlreader it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @rakesh kumar: What does, "it doesn't do anything" mean? Does it hang? Does it just exit as though it reached end of file? Are you sure that your socket reader is adding data on the producer side?

Comment: it means it keeps on doing processing ....and nothing happens. And It happens when execution reaches xmlreader.create(producerconsumerstream) and after that it doesn't come out of this function.

Answer (score 2):

XmlReader is nearly useless for XMPP, unfortunately.  It buffers to 4kB before processing any input, regardless of the stream you hook up to it.

Even as a first hack to prove this to yourself, you shouldn't write a stream that pads every inbound stanza to 4kB, but ONLY on stanza boundaries.

To get around the problem, I ported the parts of James Clark's [XP](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xp/) parser to C#.  If LGPL works for you, you could pull [xpnet](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/#svn/trunk/xpnet) out of [jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) (which I haven't updated to support WinPhone7), or send me patches if you get the entire library working.

Comment: :I extended stream to use it with XmlReader ..And seems to be working fine.