# parsing xml content coming through TCP sockets in windows phone 7

Tags: xml, parsing, sockets, windows-phone-7, xmpp

I am working on a xmpp chat application for windows phone 7.

It receives xmpp packets through the stream. Now I need to parse the xml content which comes through sockets.

For windows phone 7 we do not have SAX like parser which sits on the stream and provides us with packets.

We do not have network stream, TCP client available in windows phone 7.

\because the content comes through the stream in packets I need a stream in which I could write data on the fly.

We have a xmlreader but does not work if I use memory stream .

Do we have a SAX like parser Which could read the xml content from the socket and parse the xml content?

Please help me on how to parse the xml content coming from sockets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing xml content on windows phone 7 using tcp sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700943/parsing-xml-content-on-windows-phone-7-using-tcp-sockets)

Comment: Please edit and improve your questions, don't repost.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: they are not same there i talked about my implementation.here I am asking about a parser which could parse the xml content.though They are quiet  similar.So improving my Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlReader` should work absolutely fine on a `MemoryStream` - but remember that when you've *written* to the stream you need to "rewind" it before you start reading from it:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
// Potentially several times...
stream.Write(...);

// Rewind to the start of the stream
stream.Position = 0;

// Now read from the stream
```

Note that you don't need to use `XmlReader` explicitly - calling [`XDocument.Load(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) works fine.

Comment: :For xmlreader to work One needs to feed the memory stream in advance.And then give to xmlReader.create() ..where  xml  content comes through sockets on the fly so I need to put data in memoryStream on the fly.

Comment: @rakesh: Isn't each xmpp packet a valid XML element in its own right (possibly with some hard-coded wrapping)? If so, I don't see why you need to parse in a streaming fashion. Perhaps you could provide more information about whag you're doing in the question.

Comment: you are right xmpp packet is a valid xml but when data comes in byte array from socket.And  it can be fragmented. and My xmpp Server can send (xmpp stanzas) xml content any time so I can't be sure that it is a proper xml or not.That why I need a parser which could parse element by element.   I have another thread please look at it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700943/parsing-xml-content-on-windows-phone-7-using-tcp-sockets